# How to test proportion of each factor level against mean proportion across all levels (binary outcome)

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logistic, statistical-significance, proportion, contingency-tables

I have a dataset with the factor `region` (4 levels) and a binary variable `outcome` (0/1). Here in wide format.

```
 North East South West
     0    1     1    1
     0    0     0    0
     0    1     1    1
     0    0     1    0
     1    0     0    1
     0    1     0    1
     ...
```

The question I want to answer is: **Does the proportion of occurence for each region statistically differ from the mean proportion across all regions?** The mean is indicated by the dot in the figure below.

[image]

If the outcome was numeric, I might use a GLM approach and e.g. get t-tests (or similar tests) for each dummy variable for the regions against the grand mean. I want the same, but for proportions (i.e. binary outcomes). Note that, I explicitly want to test against the overall mean proportion across all levels of region, not use a pairwise approach. How can I do this?

**Idea**: Take the (weighted) mean of the estimated proportions and compare each region against the mean using a  proportion test (maybe using alpha correction)? Is that approach statistically sound?

Are there "standard" approaches to this problem?

Comment: Is there any reason you couldn't do a chi-squared test? You would have a 4x2 matrix (each row is a region, the columns are the counts for outcome 0 and outcome 1). The expected value in each cell is calculated as $E_{ij} = n_i \frac{X_j}{N}$ where $n_i$ is the population size of region $i$, $X_j$ is total number with outcome $j$ and $N$ is total population size. Degrees of freedom = 3 (I think). The main reason I can imagine is if the outcomes in each row are dependent?

Comment: @tristan The Chi-sqaure test is an overall test performed on a contingency table. It will not tell me which groups differ from the mean propability. I need four p-Values, not one.

Comment: OK, in that case you would probably do a two-tailed exact binomial proportion test. In R you have `binom.test` which can perform this. I would also adjust the significance level for multiple testing (from 0.05 to 0.0125). I think this is what you are saying in your "Idea", and I think it would be sound.

Answer (score 0):

You have a 4x2-contingency table, and can use a chi-squared test. But you say you want a test for each individual proportion. So use that an extension of the chi-squared test is binary logistic regression.  To get a test directly for each of the four proportions omit the intercept from the model, so, using R notation, a model like

```r
mod0 <- glm( cbind(yes,no) ~ region + 0, data=your_data,
             family=binomial) 
summary(mod0)
```

will give you four p-values.